# Setting Init Parameter for Controller from another Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service called qService which contains a method called getQ(id). My index.html resembles the following:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="qController"></div>
    <div ng-controller="dController" ng-init="init(q)">/div>
</div>
```

from qController.js I call:

```
qService.getQ(id).then(onQ);

var onQ = function(results) {
    // initialize dController from here?
};
```

My question is, how to I initialize dController with the results from the service? I'm new to Angular, but it seems like I need some somehow 're-bind' dController? Sorry if I'm not using the terminology correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check console of working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ms696v1/).

Use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to initiate the controller asyncly.

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance.

For demonstration purpose, I disable and enable the controller using `$interval`:

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('qController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$interval', function ($rootScope, $scope, $interval) {
    console.log('From qController');
    $rootScope.inited = false;

    $interval(function () {
        $rootScope.inited = true;
    }, 3000);
    $interval(function () {
        $rootScope.inited = false;
    }, 2000);
}]).controller('dController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log('From dController');
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
    <div ng-controller="qController"></div>
    <div ng-if="inited" ng-controller="dController" ng-init="init(q)"></div>
</div>
```